# Is this sum less when it contains less positive terms?

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers defined by $$x_n=
  \left\{ 
    \begin{array}{ccrcl}
      {\displaystyle\frac{1}{2k}} & \mbox{if} &
      {\displaystyle n} & {\displaystyle =} &
      {\displaystyle 2k - 1}
      \\[1mm]
      {\displaystyle\frac{1}{2k - 1}} & \mbox{if} &
      {\displaystyle n} & {\displaystyle =} &
      {\displaystyle 2k}
    \end{array}\right.
\\\epsilon_n=[\frac{1}{2}]^n\\
f(x)=\sum_{n:x_n<x}\epsilon_n
$$

(A)Compute f(1), f(1/2)

(B) Determine the set of discontinuities for the function

**Solution**

So with mathematica I computed $x_n=\{\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{7}...\}$

So, $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n:x_n<1}\frac{1}{2}^2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1-1/2}=\frac{1}{2}+2=\frac{3}{2}$

$f(\frac{1}{2})=\sum_{n:x_n<1/2}\frac{1}{2}^2=\frac{1}{1-1/2}=2$

Yet I noticed that the sum of all terms$=f(\infty)=$  $\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}^2=\frac{1}{1-1/2}=2$

Why is $f(1)$ greater than the sum of all terms, when all terms are positive? Shouldn't $f(1)<f(\infty)$

For the points of discontinuity, I think the sequence should be continuous everywhere.

Choose $\delta$ such that $\delta=x_n-x_{n-3},$ Then $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\forall y\in B_{\delta}(x_n),|x_n-y|<\delta$, $|f(x_n)-f(y)|=|f(x_n)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

For calculating $f(1)$, see that $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n<x\}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n\neq2\}$. $$f(1)=\sum_{\substack{n:x_n<x\\n \neq2}}\varepsilon^n=\dfrac12+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\left(\dfrac12\right)^n=\dfrac34$$
Similarly $$f\left(\dfrac12\right)=\sum_{n=3}^\infty\left(\dfrac12\right)^n=\dfrac14$$

So $f(x)=2>f(1)\:\:\forall\:x>1$.

$f(x)$ is discontinuous at every $x_n$. For see, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\dfrac34\neq\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=2$

[image]